# node js fails to serve mobile clients only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, angular

I have a node js server on a docker container runing on digital ocean, that serve an angular 2 application bundeled and traspiled with webpack.
When I try to get the application from any computer it works, but if I try to get it from my android device or ipad it fails to load the js files.

The browsers shows this errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED common.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED vendor.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED app.js
```

Again it works on desktop chrome/firefox/safari.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you has AdBlock or something similar in your devices? Sometimes it can cause errors like this.

Check too if you are using a proxy in the devices connection.

I hope my answer will be helpfulp!